# How to determine the nth derivative is positive or negative via an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE with some bondary conditions.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^2\varphi}{dr^2} +\frac{1}{r}\frac{d\varphi}{dr} &= \alpha \varphi\\
\end{aligned}
$$
The bondary conditions are
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d\varphi}{dr}|_{{r=0}} &= 0\\
\varphi|_{r = R} &=\xi 
\end{aligned}

And I want to determine whether the derivatives are positive $\forall r \in [0,R]$
$$\varphi(r),\frac{d\varphi}{dr},\frac{d^2\varphi}{dr^2},\frac{d^3\varphi}{dr^3}，\frac{d^4\varphi}{dr^4}$$

But HOW TO?

Actually, I used MATLAB to solve the equation numerically with ode45() function when $\alpha = 1, \xi = 10$. The solution is like an exponential function.

[image]

The analytical solution of the ODE is Bessel function.
[image]

Comment: Many functions look like exponentials. What is the solution you obtained ?

Comment: The ODE you have is that of the [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Comment: Sorry, My native language is not English and make a mistake. I have edited the question. I have used MATLAB to obtain the numerical solution(see the figure above), and I want to prove function $\varphi$ satisfy that its derivatives until 4th order is positive. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the solution is Bessel funciton which is kind of complex to me. Should I expand it as Bessel function to prove the question?

Comment: The general solution can be written as a linear combination of $I_0$ and $K_0$ (the modified Bessel functions). Apply the boundary condition at $r=0$ to rule out one of the two functions (one of them has derivative that blows up at the origin so the constant in front must be $0$). Fix the other constant by applying the second boundary condition.

Comment: Thanks, Winther! I have known that it is a standard Bessel equation and I can get its solution as a polynomial series. Then just calculate the derivatives. Beause $x \in (0,R]$ are positive, and the coefficient is positive, I get the proof!